# map<string, vector <pair<int, int> > > pushing back into pair?

Tags: c++, vector, stdmap, std-pair, push-back

I have this `map<string, vector <pair<int, int> > >` variable and I'm pushing back a value, but code::blocks is telling me that pair does not have a member function called push_back.  What should I do to get it to push back pairs rather than `pair<>.push_back()`?

This is basically what im doing:

```
map<string, vector <pair<int, int> > > T;
for(int x = 0; x < data.size(); x++)
     T[data[x].str].push_back(data[x].PAIR)
```

and the error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int>,
  std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >::push_back(std::map<int, int, 
    std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >&)'
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to push a `map` onto a `vector` of `pair`. That won't work.

Comment: oh shoot. i found it. it turns out T was a map. wow

Comment: Please mark which one is answer.

Comment: @pcbabu please dont necro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about you problem.

Following code works fine for me:

```
map<string, vector <pair<int, int> > > T;
pair<int, int> p;
p.first = 1;
p.second = 10;
T["Hello"].push_back(p);
cout << T["Hello"][0].first << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The message indicates that you are trying to push back a `std::map`, not a pair. What does your `data` structure look like?

Comment: its just a bunch of public variables (i know its not good practice). the two variables here are `string day` and `pair <int, int> T`

Answer (score 2):

Vectors do have push_back() method. Most likely data[x].PAIR is not of type pair. What type is data[x].PAIR? If you convert data[x].PAIR to pair it should work.